# Merge multiple rows to single rows which has same ID in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, dataset

I have the below dataframe

```
ID     Qnt  Rec value
AB1234  20   1   2
xy123   30   1   5
xy123   30   2   2
```

I'm looking for output like below.

I need to group by ID and when I have same ID I should bring them in same row and multiple the column Rec and Value.
Eg. For ID xy123 `30*1*5*2*2 = 600`

```
ID     Qnt  Rec Value Rec   Value  output
AB1234  20   1    2   Null  Null     40
xy123   30   1    5    2      2      600
```

My approach was I split the given data frame as Rec 1 and Rec 2 and then I merged both the dataframe. I'm looking for other feasible approach.

Edit : There is change to the Output that I'm expecting.

Comment: Why do you ignore the second `30` value on `xy123`? Your formula doesn't make sense. Can you please give an exact representation of what you are trying to compute

Comment: What should happen if the second `30` was `40`?

Comment: @Nick Qnt value would remain the same for each ID's in my DF.

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
out = (df['Rec'].mul(df['value']).groupby([df['ID'], df['Qnt']]).prod()
                .reset_index(name='output')
                .assign(output=lambda x: x['Qnt'].mul(x['output'])))
```

out

```
       ID  Qnt  output
0  AB1234   20      40
1   xy123   30     600
```

---

**Update answer**

```
s1 = df.groupby('ID').cumcount()
out = (df.set_index(['ID', 'Qnt', s1]).unstack()
         .sort_index(level=1, axis=1).droplevel(1, axis=1).reset_index()
         .assign(output=lambda x: x.prod(numeric_only=True, axis=1)))
```

out:

```
       ID  Qnt  Rec  value  Rec  value  output
0  AB1234   20  1.0    2.0  NaN    NaN    40.0
1   xy123   30  1.0    5.0  2.0    2.0   600.0
```

---

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'ID': ['AB1234', 'xy123', 'xy123'], 'Qnt': [20, 30, 30], 
         'Rec': [1, 1, 2], 'value': [2, 5, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

Comment: I've edited the output that I'm expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate with [`groupby.prod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.prod.html) the post-process:

```
out = (df
   .groupby(['ID', 'Qnt'], as_index=False).prod()
   .eval('output = Qnt*Rec*value')
   .drop(columns=['Rec', 'value'])
 )

print(out)
```

Output:

```
       ID  Qnt  output
0  AB1234   20      40
1   xy123   30     600
```

Updated question, using a [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
out = (df.assign(n=df.groupby('ID').cumcount())
         .pivot(index=['ID', 'Qnt'], columns='n')
         .sort_index(level='n', axis=1).droplevel('n', axis=1)
         .assign(output=lambda x: x.prod(axis=1))
         .reset_index()
         .eval('output = output*Qnt')
      )
```

Output:

```
       ID  Qnt  Rec  value  Rec  value  output
0  AB1234   20  1.0    2.0  NaN    NaN    40.0
1   xy123   30  1.0    5.0  2.0    2.0   600.0
```

Comment: I've edited the output that I'm expecting

Comment: @Aravind I've updated the answer, note however that modifying the question to a different logic is frowned upon, next time better ask a new question.